# Upgrading Apache Hadoop from 2.4.1 to 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop

I want to upgrade 2.4.1 to 2.6 stable version. Is it as simple as replacing all the folder contents with the latest ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the downtime is not an issue, just shut down the cluster (`bin/stop-dfs.sh`), unzip the archive with hadoop-2.6, copy configuration files that you've changed in 2.4.1 into 2.6, change the `hadoop` link so that it's now linked to the new hadoop-2.6 folder and run this command:

```
bin/start-dfs.sh -upgrade
```

After this the cluster should be started and working.

You may find more information about hadoop upgrade [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Upgrade_and_Rollback)

Comment: So once i figure out that its working then how can i resume working with normal commands like `dfs-start.sh` without the upgrade option. I Understand that the configuration file should be made compatible with 2.6 version and once done then i should be set right?

Comment: Once you've done `dfs-start.sh -upgrade` without errors, you can continue using `dfs-start.sh` without the `-upgrade` option

Comment: it remains same version not upgrading and file is start-dfs.sh not dfs-start.sh

Comment: You're right about the name of the command, I also added that you need to install (link) the hadoop-2.6 instead of just changing the config. Does this help?