# How to upgrade Hadoop Cluster from 2.6.0 to 3.0.0?

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, hadoop3

The current version of out hadoop cluster is 2.6.0-CDH5.10.0, and We want to upgrade to 3.0.0.

There are significant differences between the two versions, such as node ports being inconsistent, and so on.

How to upgrade the Hadoop Cluster from 2.6.0 to 3.0.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading Apache Hadoop from 2.4.1 to 2.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165413/upgrading-apache-hadoop-from-2-4-1-to-2-6-0)

Comment: If you're using CDH5 why not move to CDH6 which supports Hadoop 3?  You can find out more info at https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-enterprise-6.html

Answer (score 0):

CDH 5.x.x versions contains only cloudera customized hadoop-2.6.0 version.

CDH 6.0.0 Beta contains hadoop-3.0.0+cdh6.0.0-beta1 components.

You can upgrade CDH by following steps mentioned in [Upgrading to CDH 6.x Using Parcels](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/latest/topics/install_upgrade_cdh_parcels.html) document.